# Puppeteer - how to not repeat if statements to check for missing selectors

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've managed to get Puppeteer working to scrape data off a number of different web pages. However, I'm repeating the same if statement for each bit of data - I'm really new to Javascript so I'm pretty sure I'm overlooking something simple so it's not repeated.

I've searched online quite a bit & tried a few different things but can't get it working.

For the code example below, I've taken out a lot of the different query selectors so it's easier to read and just an example, but in the actual code there's 12 of them, all with exactly the same code except the querySelector.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

// This gets the url's I want to scrape stored on another file
let urls = require('./assets/links.js').urls;

(async () => { 
    // Initiate the browser 
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(); 
    
    // Create a new page with the default browser context 
    const page = await browser.newPage(); 
    
    for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    // Go to the target website 
        await page.goto(urls[i]);
        let url = urls[i];

        const title = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let element = document.querySelector('h1')
            if (element) {
                return element.innerText
                } return null;
        }) 

        const reviews = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let element = document.querySelector('.example-class')
            if (element) {
                return element.innerText
                } return null;
        }) 

        const description = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let element = document.querySelector('#example-id')
            if (element) {
                return element.innerText
                } return null;
        }) 

            console.log({ url, title, reviews, description });

    }
    // Closes the browser and all of its pages 
    await browser.close(); 
})();
```

I've tried creating a function but it wouldn't let me use it with await.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the strings. We don't have your URLs, so there's no way to know what the problem is there. I'll remove that part of the question but please post another one once it's reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple function that grabs text from a selector and returns null if the element doesn't exist:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0
const {urls} = require("./assets/links.js");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const text = sel =>
    page.$eval(sel, el => el.textContent).catch(() => null);

  for (const url of urls) {
    await page.goto(url);
    console.log({
      url,
      title: await text("h1"),
      reviews: await text(".example-class"),
      description: await text("#example-id"),
    });
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

If there's 12 of them, you might want to add an array and a loop:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.0.0
const {urls} = require("./assets/links.js");

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const text = sel =>
    page.$eval(sel, el => el.textContent).catch(() => null);

  const selectors = {
    title: "h1",
    reviews: ".example-class",
    description: "#example-id",
    // ...
  };

  for (const url of urls) {
    await page.goto(url);
    const textProms = Object.entries(selectors).map(
      async (k, sel) => [k, await text(sel)]
    );
    console.log({
      url,
      ...Object.fromEntries(await Promise.all(textProms)),
    });
  }
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```